# Jmeter in web browser

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to develop an application and embedded JMeter GUI with local html pages which are written with java scripts and normal CSS. Is it possible to integrate Jmeter GUI with local html and shows in IFrame or any other way, along with other content on same html page.

Please suggest me something how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you can parse jmeter project files, why not?

Comment: Hi Ahmet, Thanks for comment but could you please elaborate as I am not able to understand. Or would  be vely helpful if you refer me some url for working model

Answer (score 0):

You can [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) java swing application (as jmeter) to Java Web Start (JWS)
And web start can be deploy and loaded in [html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html).

Comment: Thanks for response. I have tried this but didn't work because this approach requires adding all jar files and there are many jar files in parent child relationship and it difficult to find and add all jars.